# Dijkstra algorithm with min-priority queue

Tags: graph, path, priority-queue, dijkstra, shortest-path

I'm trying to implement the dijkstra algorithm with priority queue, but I can't understand how  it works. I read many guide on the web but I can't understand this algorithm at all.

My questions are: What is the priority for each node? I think that it is the weight of the incoming edge with the minimum value, but I'm not sure. Is this true?

Second question, when I extract the root of the queue, how does it work if this node is not adjacency with no one of the visited nodes?

Comment: If you think of Dijkstra's as "Breadth-first search for weighted graphs," it becomes fairly easy to understand.  To answer your questions:  1. Not quite - it's the minimum of the edges **traversed to far**.  2. Just like with BFS, if it's not adjacent to a visited node, then it can't be visited quite yet.  If it's not *reachable* from a visited node, it won't ever be visited.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use `priority queue` where the `vertex` with the shortest distance from the starting `vertex` will get the highest priority. Initially, all `vertices` will have the shortest distance of infinity and the starting `vertex` will have the shortest distance 0.

Start by inserting of all `vertices` (with its `edges`) from the graph inside the `PQ`. Remove `vertex` from the `PQ` and explore all its `edges`. Compare the shortest distances with all adjacent `vertices` and if any distance is less than the shortest distance on the current `vertex`, update adjacent `vertex` shortest distance inside the `PQ`. Continue while `PQ` is not empty. `Vertices` which got no `edges` will finish with the shortest distance of infinity because it is not possible 'get to them' from the starting  `vertex`. However, they will be still removed from the `PQ`.

**Pseudocode**

```
initialize graph
initialize pq
pq.insertAll(graph.getVertices())

while (pq is not empty) {
  vertex = pq.remove()
  edges = vertex.getEdges()

  for all edges {
    destination = edge.getDestination()
    newDistance = edge.getLength() + vertex.getDistance()
    if (newDistance < destination.getDistance()) {
      destination.setShortestDistance(newDistance)
      pq.update(destination)
    }
  }
}
```

**MIT OpenCourseWare Links:**
[Path problems overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aa2sqUhIn-E)
[Dijkstra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2E7MmKv0Y24)

Comment: One thing I don't understand is how you keep track of the shorter edges? In this example it seems your just left with the final shortest distance (`newDistance`), rather than a list of vertices?