# How do I keep track of the shortest paths in the Dijkstra algorithm when using a min-priority queue?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, priority-queue, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm with a priority queue.

From my understanding, "Dijkstra's algorithm" allows to to find the shortest 'paths', in that it will return a **set of vertices that form the shortest path** *.

From this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20217659/1663462, as well as ([Dijkstra's_algorithm#Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Algorithm)) it seems I should be able implement it using just **two** datastructures: a graph and queue datastructure.

---

However, in my implementation using the two mentioned datastructures, when I finally reach the destination node, I don't have the vertices path stored? In other words I just have the shortest `distance` only (a single scalar value).

How is this meant to be kept track of? The only way I can think of is to use **an additional datastructure** - an array or hash map where the `key` would be the vertex and the `value` would be it's parent.

---

**The actual question:**

Is the additional datastructure necessary to achieve ("**set of vertices that form the shortest path** *")? If not, how do I determine the vertices?

Comment: Off the top of my head, and because I did the same while traversing a Neo4j graph, Yes you need to extra level of mapping. IIRC you add nodes based on distance, so each distance needs a queue, then always remove from the queue associated with the shortest distance. Also it sounds like you have the idea backwards. The first key is based on the length (distance). This would be a map of integer to queues. Then in a queue are the vertices (nodes). Since they all have the same distance (cost factor) I can't think of a reason to keep them sorted. LIFO or FIFO works.

Comment: Just a thought (haven't read all). If your vertexes are objects, you also could add a predecessor in each node (the node from you reach it over the shortest path). this way, you could simply use this instance variable to traverse backwards once you reached your target.

Comment: @jottbe would probably be better to store the predecessors in a separate table compared to directly modifying the nodes. Apart from that nitpick you're right.

Comment: @Paul: ok I think your right. I just assumed the "nodes" only are created for the dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: So this means the Wikipedia article isn't accurate with that algorithm?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski If you follow the pseudocode in the Wikipedia article you linked, you *don't* just have the shortest distance, you have both the distance and the predecessor array `prev`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998597/how-to-save-shortest-path-in-dijkstra-algorithm/28999743#28999743

Comment: Great well yes that psuedocode seems correct while the "algorithm" above / in the linked answer seem to omit the fact of needing to record what would be `prev`.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I was addressing your question "So this means the Wikipedia article isn't accurate with that algorithm?" I simply pointed out that the wikipedia article **is** correct. On the other hand, it is entirely possible to implement the algorithm **without** the predecessor array if you don't need that information. I'm unsure at this point what your actual question is.

Comment: @beaker I assumed that the "Dijkstra's algorithm" is meant to find the shortest 'paths', in that it will return a list of each nodes that form the shortest path? And I assume now that the only way to include those list of paths is with the predecessor array? Which makes me suspect that my initial assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to keep track of the whole path for each vertex as you've suggested. To produce the `s-v` paths themselves, the only thing you have to record for each vertex `v` is the edge that "discovered" it.

In other words, as a vertex `v` is being discovered by the algorithm, you record the edge `(u,v)` on which it achieved the value that minimized the distance from `s`.

Now, assuming you have the "discovering" edge for each vertex `v` in the graph, the path from `s` to `v` can be computed as follows: if `(u,v)` is the ("discovering") edge stored for `v`, then the shortest path from `s` to `v` is the path from `s` to `u` (which can be computed recursively), followed by the single edge `(u,v)`.

So, to construct the shortest path from `s` to `v`, you start at vertex `v`, then you follow the edge stored for `v` in the reverse direction, and continue until you reach `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the additional data structure is necessary, I did not find a way to do without it.

One get the shortest 'distance' without it between two vertices, but it will not include the list of vertices between the source and destination vertex.

Comment: That is not true, the additional structure is not necessary. I posted an answer explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to store additional information on the nodes while running Dijkstra's algorithm, it is not strictly necessary.

Indeed, it is possible to trace back a shortest path after running Dijkstra's algorithm, even if no additional information was stored on the nodes. The only information needed on each node is its distance from the source.

I will use the following notations:

- `s` is the source vertex;
- `t` is the destination vertex;
- `w(u,v)` is the length of edge `(u,v)` between two vertices `u` and `v` (given with the graph);
- `d(v)` is the length of the shortest path from source `s` to a vertex `v` (computed by Dijkstra).

If Dijkstra's algorithm was run correctly, then the following proposition must be true for all vertices `v` except the source:

- Vertex `v` has at least one neighbour `u` such that `d(v) = d(u) + w(u,v)`.

For every vertex `v`, call `pred(v)` that neighbour.

Then a shortest path can be constructed in reverse, starting from destination `t`, by following the `pred` vertices.